# websocket send Chinese characters

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I have a websocket server write by python and a websocket client write by javaScript.

when use English characters like 'hahaha', they can send messages to each other and work well.

when use Chinese characters like '哈哈', the server can recieve the message and  I decode the message in python side then work well. But when the server send the '哈哈' characters to the client, it said that **WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3369/' failed: Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8.**

the data I send is b'\x81\x02\xe5\x93\x88\xe5\x93\x88'. \x81 always this. \x02 means it has two characters and no masks. \xe5\x93\x88\xe5\x93\x88 represent the paylod('哈哈').

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem, thanks.

js code:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3369');

socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log('socket open');
    $('#send').click(function(){
        var data = 'dsfg';
        socket.send(data);
        console.log('click');
    });
}

socket.onmessage = function(result){
    console.log("从服务端收到的数据:");
    console.log(result.data);
}

socket.onclose = function(evt){
    console.log('socket close');
}

socket.onerror = function(evt) { 
    console.log('error:')
};
```

python code:

```
def send_data(self, data):
if data:
  data = str(data)
else:
  return False

token = b'\x81'

length = len(data)

if length < 126:
  token += struct.pack('B', length)
elif length <= 0xFFFF:
  token += struct.pack('!BH', 126, length)
else:
  token += struct.pack('!BQ', 127, length)

data = token + data.encode()

self.con.send(data)

return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The length part must be length **in bytes**. So, use 6 as the value of the second byte like below.

`\x81\x06\xe5\x93\x88\xe5\x93\x88`

Comment: thank you, this work for me. this question takes me one afternoon, but now it looks so simple!!! no no no.